# Can too many PHP warnings cause a script to abort without throwing a fatal error? How do you catch that?

Tags: php

I have an extremely complicated PHP script (probably goes through 100,000+ lines of code) before finishing.  Once in a blue-moon it just stops mid-way (according to the debug logs), and I'm not sure why.  I do see 115 warnings in the PHP log for that thread when it failed, but my custom `register_shutdown_function` never seemed to hit.  That showdown function, upon a fatal error (`$last_error['type'] === E_ERROR`) writes to a text log file, then pushes me an alert on Slack (so I can immediately investigate), but it did neither here.

All I can think of is that the server ran out of memory due to too many warnings or something, but even when a thread has taken too much memory in the past it still records via my shutdown function.

Is there some other place I can look for handling this?  (I am cleaning up my warnings, but it's a long fight given how much code there is.)

Comment: Check the server log to see if the script is crashing.

Comment: Lots of warnings are an indication that the code is poorly written, but it shouldn't cause the script to abort.

Comment: Short answer: no, warnings do not crash your code, even 1150

Comment: Check the general server logs. If the OS decides to terminate the process due to something like a low-memory condition it is not shut down gracefully, simply killed. This will be logged somewhere like `/var/log/messages` or similar depending on your distro.

Comment: I'm not a terribly great systems guy myself, but I did search our server (ubuntu on AWS) in the `/var/log/syslog` (there is no `messages`), the `php8.0-fpm.log` (which is where I found the warnings, but again: no fatals), nothing in the `www.log.slow` that matches.

@Barmar Is there anywhere specific you think I should search?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know where the webserver log is on AWS.

Comment: One possibility is that there was an error, and *then* there was a warning, during automatic clean-up, before your shutdown function ran, so the "last error" would not be the fatal error. A common use of the shutdown handler is to make it more likely the user will see a friendly error rather than a blank screen, but it is not explicitly designed for detecting errors. To ensure you capture all errors, you should be using set_error_handler() and set_exception_handler(), or just the built in error logging.